# Problems with hibernate and persisence.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to make my first hibernate app and after running my main I get these errors:

```
gru 12, 2019 7:00:03 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: hibernate-dynamic
    ...]
gru 12, 2019 7:00:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.0.Final}

gru 12, 2019 7:00:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
gru 12, 2019 7:00:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at hibernate.model.Dyrektor.main(Dyrektor.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 12 more
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="hibernate-dynamic" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:PUBLIC;sql.syntax_ora=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What can I do with it? I tried many solutions but none of them work, hope anyone could help me because it makes me very frustraded..

Comment: I would suggest that you try and frame a more specific question rather than "I did stuff, it didn't work, please help." Folks can typically only help when you ask a specific question, such as "I did x, expected y but got z instead. Why?" or something like that.

Start by looking at why `javax.xml.bind.JAXBException` is not found.

Comment: You are on Java11 which has the JAXB classes removed, you need to add the JAXB dependencies to your classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)